# Is Old Betsy immune to dynamite and gasoline?

Tags: last-night-on-earth

If *Old Betsy* is placed on the board and *dynamite* is subsequently thrown onto that space or a *gas marker* in that space is ignited, what happens to *Old Betsy*?

The rules for *dynamite* say:

> Roll a D6 for each model in that space. Zombies are Killed on the roll
>   of 2+. Any Hero in that space is Killed on the roll of 5+.

Does *Old Betsy* automatically survive, or does she count as a Hero in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old betsy will survive. The only things affected are those listed on the card (zombies and heroes)